# TCP client not sending ACK

Tags: linux, tcp

I have a python based HTTP client and a server. Lately I saw several timeouts on the client's end when POSTing data.

I ran a Tcpdump on both the ends and figured out that the client was replying with ACK in the TCP handshake.I saw that the client was sending only `S` flags whereas the server was sending `S.` flags.

Any idea why this would happen or how to troubleshoot it ?

Comment: Did you write this software yourself? Does the software use raw sockets or the native TCP socket stack?

Comment: It uses the request module in python. So, uses the native TCP sockets